# Mesclar arrays php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!

Existe a possibilidade de unir array's ?

Se sim como posso fazer ?

**O que tenho**

```
Array
(
    [Dashboard_1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [Configuração_2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [Usuário_3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [Criar_4] => 1
)
Array
(
    [Editar_5] => 1
)
Array
(
    [Excluir_6] => 1
)
Array
(
    [Visualizar_7] => 1
)
```

**O que desejo**

```
Array
(
    [Dashboard_1] => 1
    [Configuração_2] => 1
    [Usuário_3] => 1
    [Criar_4] => 1
    [Editar_5] => 1
    [Excluir_6] => 1
    [Visualizar_7] => 1
)
```

**Função**

```
// edit_jstree
public function edit_jstree($dados, $permissao_id)
{
    //print_r($dados);
    $array = (array) $dados;
    foreach ($dados as $js)
    {
        $jstree = [
            'acesso'  => $js['state']->selected,
        ];
        $this->db->where('identificacao', $js['id']);
        $this->db->where('permissao_id', $permissao_id);
        $this->db->update('tb_jstree', $jstree);

        $array_chave = $js['text'].'_'.$js['id']; // concatena texto + identifiacao para montar a chave do array

        $array = [
            "$array_chave"  => $js['state']->selected,
        ];

        $array_serialize = serialize($array);           
        print_r($array_serialize);
    }           
}
```

Comment: Utilize o `array_merge`

Comment: Já tentei, mas pelo que percebi, seguindo o manual, `array_merge` precisa de dois parâmetros, e eu só tenho um `$array`.

Comment: A função array_merge só tem um parâmetro "obrigatório" (Combina um ou mais arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema reside na função `edit_jstree()` você está fazendo um **"loop"** e envelopando cada item em um `{Array}` ... poderia simplesmente declara um `{Array}` antes do `foreach()` e adicionar chave valor durante o **"loop"**, posteriormente "printar" (ou retornar):

```
// edit_jstree
public function edit_jstree($dados, $permissao_id)
{
    // declarar uma variável (Array)
    $base_array = [];
    //print_r($dados);
    $array = (array) $dados;
    foreach ($dados as $js)
    {
        $jstree = [
            'acesso'  => $js['state']->selected,
        ];
        $this->db->where('identificacao', $js['id']);
        $this->db->where('permissao_id', $permissao_id);
        $this->db->update('tb_jstree', $jstree);

        $array_chave = $js['text'].'_'.$js['id']; // concatena texto + identifiacao para montar a chave do array

        $base_array[$array_chave] = $js['state']->selected;
    }        
    print_r($base_array);   
}
```

Comment: Perfeito @LauroMoraes.

Answer (score 1):

Poderá utilizar a função array_merge( array $array1 [, array $... ] )

Segue um exemplo:

```
<?php
$a= array();
$a['xpto'] = 'aa';
$b= array();
$b['xyzz'] = 'bb';

$c = array_merge($a, $b);
print_r($c);
?>
```

Comment: Eu não tenho o parâmetro `$a e $b`, eu só tenho o `$a`, neste caso `$array`.
Já tentei com `array_merge` e `array_unique`

Comment: Pode mandar um exemplo? da chamada à sua função?

Comment: A função array_unique  remove os duplicados. Você não quer unir arrays?

Comment: Sim, quero unir arrays

Comment: tentei assim e não deu. `$array = [
       "$array_chave"  => $js['state']->selected,
   ];
   
   print_r(array_merge($array));`

Comment: o seu array não está bem definido

Comment: <?php
$js = array();
$js['state'] = array();
$js['state']['selected'] = 'AAA';
$array_chave = 'chave';
$array = [$array_chave => $js['state']['selected']]; 
print_r(array_merge($array));

Comment: o problema não é a função array_merge, veja o array que está a passar para mesma

Comment: faça um print_r de $js, de $js['state'] e $js['state']['selected'] para ver os valores

Comment: atenção que também de de ser $array_chave => e não ""$array_chave".... $array_chave é uma variável e não é uma string

Comment: Veja o print de $js e $js['state']->selected: https://pastebin.com/0pecNAfz

Comment: Eu testei a sua função dentro do laço e ficou igual o array da pergunta.
Então coloquei fora do laço, daí só apareceu `Array
(
    [chave] => AAA
)`

Comment: qual é a finalidade do loop?

Comment: veja a resposta do Lauro, parece estar correta, não sabia que era que você queria devolver um array no final.... pelo que, perguntei a finalidade do loop

Comment: Funcionou sim, obrigado..